# How to communicate Select Any (future and present) vs Select All (present) in multi-select input?

Tags: usability, forms

We're making a trend/policy builder, and our default checkbox list dropdown has a wired UX bug.

When the client 'selects all' he selects all present options, but then the trend doesn't include new options added over time (let's say the client creates policy for 'all' vendors).

Where I work, the debate is about adding 'select any' to the 'select all' in the default drop down.

Is there a good way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

"Select Any" lets the user convey that they don't have a preference on what is selected; "Select All" conveys that they are deliberately opting into all of the  options.

You might want these to be in separate controls so that users aren't thinking too hard about the semantic difference between "Select All" and "Select Any". Perhaps two radios, like:

(•) Show me any topic

( ) Show these topics: [ Select... ]

"Select All" could still be part of the dropdown in the second control, to help ease the selection of a large amount of topics.